# Need some help with a power series thing

Tags: sequences-and-series

Okay i'm given the equation 
$$f(x) =\frac{x}{x+1}$$
I need to find a power series representation.
I know that:
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
So. Would I separate it as
$$ x * \frac{1}{x+1} $$ 
then factor i a negative so it ends up being
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(x)^{n+1} $$

?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Your title is wrong ;) You didn't need help, just some confirmation.

Comment: Indeed, it stands correct. Good luck with everything else you're working on!

Comment: haha you guys are the best!

Answer (score 1):

What you did, or also

$$\frac x{1+x}=1-\frac1{1+x}=1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}x^n\;\ldots$$